# Marmelab react-admin x-total-count how to add new headers

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?

how to add in response headers ??

Comment: Add some of your code samples.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.set('Content-Range',`<name-of-section> */<total-count-say-50>`);
response.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using express:

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    ...
    //the variable total holds the value we want to pass in the header     
    res.set({ 
            'X-Total-Count': total,
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers':'X-Total-Count'
    });
    ...
})
```

Example using nest.js:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Param, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
//Important!!
import { Response } from 'express';

@Controller('examples')
export class ExampleController {

    ...

  @Get()
  async getExamples(@Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response) {
    ...
    //the variable total holds the value we want to pass in the header     
    res.set({ 
            'X-Total-Count': total,
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers':'X-Total-Count'
            });
   ...
  }
```